# using hasclass for multiple divs with one button Problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am trying to change the display property of a div based on if the carousel image is active at the time. I have gotten it to work but it only works when i doubleclick. With a single click it displays the div corresponding to the previous active image instead of the current one. Please HELP.

=====================================

## CODE BELOW

### HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="siteImgs">
  <div class="row col-xs-12 col-md-7">
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Carousel indicators -->

   <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" id="lg" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" id="ma"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" id="sz"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"id="ti"></li>
   </ol>   

  <!-- Carousel items -->

 <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
        <img src="img/work/lookingGlass.png" alt="looking glass">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <img src="img/work/mauriceSite.png" alt="maurice site">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <img src="img/work/sza.png" alt="sza">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <img src="img/work/tina.png" alt="tina">
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Carousel nav -->
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
 </a>
 </div>

</div>


<!--INFORMATION DIVS-->

<div class="row col-xs-12 col-md-5 lookingGlass lg">
      <h1>THE LOOKING GLASS</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>

 <div class="row col-xs-12 col-md-5 lookingGlass ma">
      <h1>MAURICEDANIELS.COM</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>

<div class="row col-xs-12 col-md-5 lookingGlass sz">
      <h1>SZA</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>

<div class="row col-xs-12 col-md-5 lookingGlass ti">
      <h1>TINA D. PHOTOGRAPHY</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

### JS/JQUERY

```
        $( '.ma' ).hide();
    $( '.sz' ).hide(),
    $( '.ti' ).hide();
$( ".carousel-control" ).click(function() {

if ( $( '#lg' ).hasClass( "active" ) ) {

    $( '.lg' ).show(),
    $( '.ma' ).hide();
    $( '.sz' ).hide(),
    $( '.ti' ).hide();

}

if ( $( '#ma' ).hasClass( "active" ) ) {

    $( '.ma' ).show(),
    $( '.lg' ).hide();
    $( '.sz' ).hide(),
    $( '.ti' ).hide();

}

if ( $( '#sz' ).hasClass( "active" ) ) {

    $( '.sz' ).show(),
    $( '.lg' ).hide();
    $( '.ma' ).hide(),
    $( '.ti' ).hide();

}

if ( $( '#ti' ).hasClass( "active" ) ) {

    $( '.ti' ).show(),
    $( '.lg' ).hide();
    $( '.sz' ).hide(),
    $( '.ma' ).hide();

}

});
```

[Full Example HERE](http://cmeeinspire.com/work-Site.html)

Comment: try `$( ".carousel-control" ).on('click',function() {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [slide event](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) for this.

```
 $('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {

        var index = $(e.relatedTarget).index();
        var obj = $('[data-slide-to="' + index + '"]').attr('id');

        $('.lookingGlass').hide();        // all individual hide() that you had in your code can be replaced by targeting the divs with class

        $('.' + obj).show();
  })
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/nb0qhz8t/2/)

Also another way is to remove the ids from the carousel indicators and add it as a data-attribute to `div.item` something like this `<div class="item" data-target="lg">` and use it like this

```
 $('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
        var obj = $(e.relatedTarget).data('target');
        $('.lookingGlass').hide();
        $('.' + obj).show();
  })
```

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/nb0qhz8t/3/)

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like that,

```
$( ".carousel-control" ).click(function() {
  $(".carousel-indicators").each(function(){

    var idActive = $(this).attr("id");

    if($(".lookingGlass ").hasClass("idActive ")){
         $(this).show();

    }
     $(".lookingGlass").hide();
  });
});
```

And im not if its gonna work just wrote it here, can check it after 15 min from now on, but maybe its help you now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work, but looking at your site, and how the carousel works, there is a delay to which the class "active" is applied when images/slides are switching.  I think whats happening is that this delay causes the carousel's bootstrap js to mismatch a little with your custom js, so that when you click, the previous slide is still active, then the bootstrap js kicks in and switches the slide, but your js has already executed, thus causing the mismatch in divs vs images displayed.  Instead of using "active" class to determine, try using:

```
if ($('#ti').hasClass("next") || $('#ti').hasClass("prev") {
    // do stuff here
}
```